# "Complex" plotting with plottly.express

Tags: python, plotly

[image: This my dataframe]

What I am trying to do is something like this using plotly.express:
[image: here]

It partly worked, but I wish each part of the bars would be different colors
and that it showed the value in the columns 'CBK_total' and 'Estorno_total'
on each individual part of each bar. Don't know if it's possible.

My code:

```
performance_mes_CBK = px.bar(dados
         , x='Ano_Mes_Solicitacao'
         , y=['Prop_CBK', 'Prop_Estorno']
         , color='Regra'
         , barmode='group'
         , height=600
         , title='Performance Regras')
```

Answer (score 0):

- when asking questions,  provide your data as marked up text, not a screen shot.  Doing OCR on data is not straight forward
- this can be achieved using opacity encoded into `rgba()`.  Understanding that **marker_color** can be a value or an array
- have restructured dataframe to stack y-values into a column, with another column showing which measure it is
- can then use `for_each_trace()` to update **marker_color** using assigned color and column that has been included in **customdata** through use of **hover_data**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.colors

# simulate data frame... data as images in questions is unusable
s = 100
dados = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "Ano_Mes_Solicitacao": np.random.choice(
            pd.date_range("1-oct-2021", freq="MS", periods=4), s
        ),
        "Prop_CBK": np.random.randint(20, 50, s),
        "Prop_Estorno": np.random.randint(20, 50, s),
        "Regra": np.random.choice([0.0, 1.0, 2.0], 100).astype(str),
    }
)
dados = dados.groupby(["Ano_Mes_Solicitacao", "Regra"], as_index=False).sum()

# OP code, from simulated dataframe
performance_mes_CBK = px.bar(
    dados,
    x="Ano_Mes_Solicitacao",
    y=["Prop_CBK", "Prop_Estorno"],
    color="Regra",
    barmode="group",
    height=600,
    title="Performance Regras",
)

performance_mes_CBK.show()

# restruct dataframe so that data is stacked
d2 = (
    dados.set_index(["Ano_Mes_Solicitacao", "Regra"])
    .stack()
    .to_frame()
    .reset_index()
    .rename(columns={"level_2": "column", 0: "value"})
)

# utility function to set transparency based on which measure is being displayed
def color_array(t):
    r, g, b = plotly.colors.hex_to_rgb(t.marker.color)
    return [
        f"rgba({r},{g},{b},{1 if v==t.customdata[0] else .6})"
        for v in t.customdata.T[0]
    ]

# use hover_data to create custom data so that measures are identifable
# update marker_color to use transparency function
fig = px.bar(
    d2,
    x="Ano_Mes_Solicitacao",
    y="value",
    color="Regra",
    barmode="group",
    height=600,
    hover_data=["column"],
    title="Performance Regras",
).for_each_trace(lambda t: t.update(marker_color=color_array(t)))

fig
```

[image]